# How to collapse unused parameters in moderncv's \cventry-command?

Tags: moderncv

I am writing my CV using the moderncv package. I want to adjust the CV to meet my needs. Therefore I amplified the maximum number of parameters possible in the \cventry command. However, now I have some ugly spacing in case I do NOT use all parameters as shown in the attached pic (ugly spacing is marked with red). Please see also my MWE. In general there are two scenarios:
First (please see the first red box), using four parameters I obtain ugly spacing.
Second (please refer to second red box), using three parameters I obtain the same ugly spacing.

So, what I would like to obtain is to have "intelligent" commands. Depending on the number of parameters used (which will at least be three, as done in case of second red box), I want latex to collapse the spacing. Is that possible?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.7]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

\renewcommand*{\cventry}[9][.4em]{% 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\bfseries #4} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}        {\bfseries #5\\} \itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6} & \ifthenelse{\equal{#2#7}{}}{\\}{\itshape #2\\} \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{#7\\}     \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{#8\\}% 
\end{tabular*}% 
\par\addvspace{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Education}
\cventry{Grade}{Degree}{Institution}{year--year}{M.Sc.}{Majors}{Majors}{}
\cventry{}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{}{}{}{}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{Grade}{Majors}{Majors}{}
\end{document}
```